# How to script renaming multiple files according to a common pattern in DOS?

Tags: command, dos

I have set of image files named like this:

```
  GOPR0059 01_pt.jpg
  GOPR0059 02_pt.jpg
  GOPR0059 03_pt.jpg
  GOPR0059 04_pt.jpg
  GOPR0059 05_pt.jpg
  GOPR0059 06_pt.jpg
  GOPR0059 07_pt.jpg
```

so on

I would like to rename these files these

```
IMG_1.jpg
IMG_2.jpg
IMG_3.jpg
IMG_4.jpg
IMG_5.jpg
IMG_6.jpg
IMG_7.jpg
```

I am not getting REN command in dos to work for this.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`REN "GOPR0059 *_pt.jpg" "IMG_*.jpg"`

It won't give you exactly what you need because of the leading 0's but it should go in the right direction

Comment: Thanks, i was wondering whether there is a way to fix a problem with space in the name: GOPR0059 01_pt.jpg i Have similar problem with some other file names like NRT 01_pt is there a way to rename it to img_1 so on without have to change to gopr0059 or NRT in ren command.

Comment: you wont be able to rename two sets of files because it would require two wildcards. I would recommend doing some kind of batch script to accomplish that. There are also several freewares that will allow you to batch rename files with a little more complexity. If it were me though, I would use cygwin and bash scripting